# How to force hibernate insert foreign key value together with general insert into table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys

I have mapping like this(unidirectional):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TEMPLATE")
public class MyTemplate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MY_TEMPLATE_ID")
    private List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_OBJECT")
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
}
```

then I write code like this:

```
MyTemplate mt = new MyTemplate();
mt.setField1(someVal1);
mt.setField2(someVal2);
mt.setField3(someVal2);

MyObject mdr = new MyObject ();
mt.getMyObjects.add(mdr);//!!!
mdr.setFfld1(smVal1);
mdr.setFfld2(smVal2);
mdr.setFfld3(smVal3);
```

crudRepository.save(mt);

Hibernate generates 3 query for that:

1. insert into `MY_TEMPLATE` for `field1`, `field2` anf `field3`
2. insert into `MY_OBJECT` for `fld1`, `fld2` and `fld3`
3. update set foreign key for `MY_OBJECT` table

Is it possible to force hibernate to insert FK together with insert into `MY_OBJECT` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following and it helped:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "MY_TEMPLATE_ID", nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vlad Mihalcea explains this in his [article about 1-many relationships](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

> If you take a look at Hibernate flush order, you’ll see that the persist action is executed before the collection elements are handled. This way, Hibernate inserts the child records first without the Foreign Key since the child entity does not store this information. During collection handling phase, the Foreign Key column is updated accordingly.

He recommends reversing the relationship into a `@ManyToOne` relationship or into a bidirectional relationship controlled by the *many* side.

Comment: what do you mean 'reversing the relationship into a @OneToMany relationship' ?

Comment: Sorry, messed that part up. Into `@ManyToOne` is correct, i.e. `MyDailyResource` should reference `MyTable`.

Comment: for some reason it is impossible